# C# - Checking whether byte array is a valid video file, and of what type

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a system that saves temporary files in windows\temp. These files take on a .tmp file extension.

I am working on functionality that needs to read one of these files, identify whether it is an image or video file, and the filetype. Since the files are saved as .tmp, I can not use the file extension.

I've already written code that identifies whether the file is a valid image file, and it's filetype - This was actually quite easy, to my surprise!

My question is this: How can I identify whether an array of bytes is a valid video file, and if it is, how can I identify it's filetype?

Comment: `I've already written code that identifies whether the file is a valid image file, and it's filetype - This was actually quite easy, to my surprise!` How?

Comment: Add some more details on the code and where you're having problems.

Comment: Nikhil - The code I wrote is here - http://pastebin.com/HBxqLmer . It's based on suggestions and approaches I found here on SO.

Comment: Luke - That's the thing, I haven't written any code for this problem, because I haven't figured out how to approach it. :)

Comment: check the ContentType of the file? it wil lgive the MimeType. Then you just need to see if it's mp4 or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, this is in general not an easy task as there are hundreds of formats. But I guess if you learn about *binary signatures*, or *file signatures*, you'll get a step forward with this question.

Here is an idea:
[http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Binary_Signatures](http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer%3aBinary_Signatures)

And here more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Good luck :-)